# How to get the value for a nested item inside a collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Suppose I have this document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e2f2af16f1e7e4c2000000a"),
    "location" : {
        "geometry" : [
            [ 123, 23.45321 ],
            [ 124.55632, 43.256 ]
        ]
    },
    "advertisers" : {
        "created_at" : ISODate("2011-07-26T21:02:19Z"),
        "category" : "Infinity Pro Spin Air Brush",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2011-07-26T21:02:19Z"),
        "lowered_name" : "conair",
        "twitter_name" : "",
        "facebook_page_url" : "",
        "website_url" : "",
        "user_ids" : [ ],
        "blog_url" : ""
    }
}
```

I just wanted to get the specific value inside 'advertisers' let's say lowered_name.

Querying, I can have this kind of syntax:

```
db.advertisers.find({"advertisers.lowered_name" : "conair"})
```

But ofcourse it would return documents that equals to the query. How can I just get the specific value "conair". For example using it in a print statement: using such code will result to an error:

```
for cursor in results:
    print(cursor["advertisers.lowered_name"])
```

How can this be done? I tried searching, but hmmm I might've missed it somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried `db.advertisers.distinct("advertisers.lowered_name")` ?

Comment: @Veeram hi, I think distinct will still return one whole document. Like findOne. What I need is just to get the value of advertisers.lowered_name

Comment: Use the projection: `.find({"advertisers.lowered_name" : "conair"}, {"advertisers.lowered_name": 1})`

Comment: @Veeram ah I just tried it. I did get the values for the distinct values, however in the whole collection. I would need to get individual values in a loop for manipulation

Comment: @M.StyvaneSoukossi close enough but doing 'db.advertisers.find({"_id":id}, {"advertisers.lowered_name"}) will result to a filtered result where I guess I can get a printout of '{"lowered_name" : "conair"}  if I did 'print(cursor[advertisers])'

Comment: If you use `_id` in your query field then `find` will return a cursor object which "contains" one document because `_id` value are unique across the collection in which case, you should use the `find_one()` method which means you don't need the iteration aka for loop

Comment: @M.StyvaneSoukossi ah sorry that was a bad example for find. but basically my implementation would actually be querying at most 2 documents thus the loop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the embedded field using the "dot notation" using Pymongo because Pymongo use *dictionary to represent document*.

```
for item in db.advertisers.find({"advertisers.lowered_name" : "conair"}, {"advertisers.lowered_name": 1}):
    print(item["advertisers"]["lowered_name"])
```

You can also use the `.distinct` method but bear in mind that this will only return a list of unique "lowered_name"

```
for item in db.advertisers.distinct("advertisers.lowered_name", {"advertisers.lowered_name" : "conair"}):
    print(item)
```